# Understanding the example on lvalue-to-rvalue conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr, lvalue-to-rvalue

I have a hard time understanding how this code (an example from the C++14 draft standard *[conv.lval]*) invokes undefined behavior for `g(false)`. Why does `constexpr` make the program valid?

Also, what does it mean by "does not access `y.n`"? In both calls to `g()` we are returning the `n` data member so why does the last line say it doesn't access it?

```c++
struct S { int n; };
auto f() {
    S x { 1 };
    constexpr S y { 2 };
    return [&](bool b) { return (b ? y : x).n; };
}
auto g = f();
int m = g(false); // undefined behavior due to access of x.n outside its
                  // lifetime
int n = g(true);  // OK, does not access y.n
```

Comment: My guess is that `constexpr` is evaluated at compile time and is stored in some read-only section of the program independent of the stack frame while `x` is in the stack frame, and accessing it after the stack frame has been deleted is causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Where did you find this example?  In the Standard, or another source?

Comment: @BenVoigt It's from C++14 [conv.lval]/2.2.

Comment: @BenVoigt your comments were very helpful. I actually just started digging into the ODR rules due to some recent SO questions w.r.t to constexpr and ODR that concerned me. The relatively new wording is not straight-forward and the few explanations out there are not great.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Yeah I really don't like the term "potential results of an expression" that has absolutely nothing to do with the "result" of that same expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `y.n` is not odr-used and therefore does not require an access to `y.n` the rules for odr-use are covered in `3.2` and says:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex **is odr-used unless** applying the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x **yields a constant expression** (5.19) that does not invoke any non-trivial
>   functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, where
>   **either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e**, or e is a discarded-value expression

Note, Ben Voigt made some helpful comments that clarified this one a bit. So the working assumption here is that *x* would be:

```
y
```

and *e* would be(*the different expression that e is defined for is covered in paragraph 2 of section 3.2*):

```
(b ? y : x).n
```

`y` yields a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to the expression *e*.

Since `f` yields a lambda which captures `f`'s local variables by reference `x` is no longer valid once the call to `f` is done since `x` is an automatic variable inside `f`. Since `y` is a *constant expression* it acts as if `y.n` was not accessed and therefore we don't have the same lifetime issue.

Your example is included in [N3939](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `4.1` *[conv.lval]* and right before that example it says:

> When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to an expression e, and either

and includes the following bullet which the examle belongs to:

> the evaluation of e results in the evaluation of a member ex of the set of potential results of e, and
>   ex names a variable x that **is not odr-used** by ex (3.2),

then:

> the **value contained in the referenced object is not accessed**

This was applied to the C++14 draft standard due to [defect report 1773](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3953.html#1773) .

Comment: What does it mean by "the value contained in the referenced object is not accessed"? `2` is the value of `y.n` so does that mean I don't get `2` back from `g(true)`?

Comment: You do get back 2 from `g(true)` but the program didn't have to access a physical memory location named `y.n` to get that value.