# Confusion in Scope and Life Time of a local variable in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, scope, local-variables, lifetime

**My question is that when the lifetime of a local variable is at block level then why the pointer is still printing the value of a local variable even outside the block**

```
 #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

int main(){

    int *p;
    {
        int n;
        n=5;
        p=&n;
    } 
    cout<<*p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Scope* refers to the the availability of an identifier.
*Life time* refers to the actual duration an object is alive and accessible legally during the execution of the program. They are distinct things.

Your code has [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the lifetime of  the object `n` is over at the closing `}` because you access it through a pointer.

A simple example might make it clearer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *func()
{
static int var = 42;
return &r;
}

int main(void)
{
int *p = func();
*p = 75; // This is valid.
}
```

Here, `var` is has `static` storage duration. i.e. it's alive until the program termination. However, the scope of the variable `var` is limited to the function `func()`. But `var` can be accessed even outside `func()` through a pointer. This is perfectly valid.

Compare this to your program. `n` has automatic storage duration and its lifetime and scope both are limited to the enclosing brackets `{ }`. So it's invalid to access `n` using a pointer.

However, if you make change its (`n`) storage class to `static` then you can do what you do as the object is alive even outside enclosing brackets.