# Are const built in types inlined in c++?

Tags: c++, constants, inline

I looked the C++14 reference and could not see where the standard would says that the const built in types are inlined by the compiler and not allocated. i.e. the claim is

```
const int i = 5;
std::cout<<i;
```

everywhere i is used with be replaced with 5 and no memory space will be allocated. Can someone please point to the standard section ?

Comment: What does it mean to "inline a type"??

Comment: Data types are not inlined.  Functions and methods may be inlined, depending on the compiler's optimization settings.

Comment: Seems like you are not using the terminology correctly, can you provide a reference? Seems like you are asking when a variable is odr used like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28506342/1708801).

Comment: Try section 3.2 perhaps.

Comment: The "optimization" technique you are talking about dates way back in history to the C language.  In the modern language specifications, the optimization may fall under the "as-if" rule.

Comment: Why do you presume this is guaranteed somewhere in the Standard?  Inling is allowed for any given point of usage (unless taking the address / initialising a reference etc.), but not required - up to the compiler/optimiser.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a combination of two concepts *odr use* and the *as-if rule*.

Odr-use, which would be covered in covered in section `3.2` *One definition rule* but we can also find some relevant section in `4.1` *Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion* which says:

> When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to an expression e, and
>   either
>
> - e is not potentially evaluated, or
> - the evaluation of e results in the evaluation of a member ex of the set of potential results of e, and ex names a **variable x that is not
>     odr-used** by ex (3.2),
>
> **the value contained in the referenced object is not accessed.**

and has the following involved example which seems to show a captured by reference local variable being used outside of its lifetime but is actually not the case since it is not odr-used and therefore does not actually require the object to be allocated and thus can be optimized away.

> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S { int n; };
> auto f() {
>     S x { 1 };
>     constexpr S y { 2 };
>     return [&](bool b) { return (b ? y : x).n; };
> }    
> auto g = f();
> int m = g(false); // undefined behavior due to access of x.n outside its lifetime
> int n = g(true); // OK, does not access y.n
> ```
>
> —end example ]

This comes down to the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) which says the compiler only has the emulate the observable behavior of a program, basically it governs what optimizations are allowable. Even though an optimization may be allowable the compiler does not have to perform the optimization. If an object yields a constant expression and the address is not required then by the *as-if rule* no memory needs to be allocated for it since the effect of not allocating memory would not be observable.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the compiler will emit processor instructions containing the constant value and not allocate a read/write memory location.  But this depends on the compiler settings.

The compiler may elect to place the constants into a read-only section of memory.  It may place the constant into the executable.

Print out the assembly language listing of the function to see the truth.

Comment: Or open the memory mapping file and check the symbols.