# Why does constexpr static member (of type class) require a definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, c++14, constexpr

==> See the full snippet code and compilation on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6ebe0ef8a87b601).

I have a [LiteralType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType) class filling [`constexpr` requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

```
struct MyString
{
    constexpr MyString(char const* p, int s) : ptr(p), sz(s) {}
    constexpr char const* data() const { return ptr; }
    constexpr int         size() const { return sz;  }

    char const *ptr = 0;
    int  const  sz  = 0;
};
```

I use it as a [`constexpr static`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) member variable:

```
struct Foo
{
    int size() { return str_.size(); }

    constexpr static MyString str_{"ABC",3};
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  return ! foo.size();
}
```

But the linker says:
<sup>(Clang-3.5 and GCC-4.9)</sup>

```
undefined reference to `Foo::str_'
```

I have to define the `constexpr static` member!
<sup>(I do not specify the constructor parameters)</sup>

```
constexpr MyString Foo::str_;
```

However if the `constexpr static` member had been an `int` the member would not have to be defined outside the class definition. This is my understanding, but I am not sure...

#### Questions:

- Why `int` does not need to be defined outside the class declaration but `MyString` requires this?
- Is there a disadvantage to define a `constexpr static` member in a header file? 
   (I provide my library as header files only)

Comment: If it is [oder-used it must be defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8016780/1708801)

Comment: Thanks @ShafikYaghmour for the link. I do not know about `odr-used`. Please could you provide more within an answer. You can also explain if you advice to define the member within the header file... Cheers

Comment: static const int has been special cased since before c++11.  Even then if you ever need the address of a static const int you must provide a definition in addition to the declaration.

Comment: Perfect @DaleWilson I understand :-) But do I have to provide also a ".cpp" file with my lib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [One Definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) tells us that we can not have more than one definition of an [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) variable in a program. So if a variable is odr-used then you need to define it but you can not define it the header file since it may be included more than once with the whole program. Odr-use violations do not require a diagnostic message and so you can violate this rule and the compiler is not obliged to notify you.

In your case you are indeed odr-using `str_`, and you can not include the definition in the header file because that would violate the one definiton rule since it can be included more than once within the program.

It is interesting to note that if you had done the following it would not have been odr-used:

```
return str_.size_;
```

You would therefore not need to define the variable, [which can have some odd consequences in some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28506342/1708801). I doubt that really solves your problem long-term.

The odr rules are covered in the draft C++ standard section `3.2` and they say:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   ex is odr-used unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1)
>   to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any
>   non-trivial functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the
>   set of potential results of an expression e, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5). this is odr-used if it appears
>   as a potentially-evaluated expression (including as the result of the
>   implicit transformation in the body of a non-static member function
>   (9.3.1)).[...]

So `str_` yield a constant expression, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied the expression `str_.size()` and it is not a discarded value expression, so it is odr-used and therefore `str_` is required to be defined.

On the other hand the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to the expression `str_.size_`, so it is not odr-used and does not require `str_` to be defined.