# Using `constexpr` with array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

I know that in C++11, I can write

```
class foo {
    static constexpr const char *one = "one";
}
```

However, when I try to do the same for an array

```
class bar {
    static constexpr const float prim[4] = {2, 3, 5, 7};
}
```

(and reference it later on) I get an `undefined reference` linker error.

Is this just not possible for arrays or am I missing something in the syntax?

Comment: The declaration and usage of this example compiles fine on GCC 7.2

Comment: Look at good answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397864/why-does-constexpr-static-member-of-type-class-require-a-definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static constexpr data member declarations aren't definitions in C++11/14, therefore you cannot odr-use `prim`.
To work around it, put the following statement somewhere in your cpp file as you would do with any other non-constexpr static data member:

```
constexpr const float bar::prim[4];
```

---

In other terms, this returns an undefined reference:

```
struct bar {
    static constexpr const float prim[4] = {2, 3, 5, 7};
};

int main() {
    auto *foo = bar::prim;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
struct bar {
    static constexpr const float prim[4] = {2, 3, 5, 7};
};

constexpr const float bar::prim[4];

int main() {
    auto *foo = bar::prim;
}
```

Because in the second case you are actually defining `prim` other than declaring it and thus you can get its address, use it by means of a reference, and so on...

Comment: Is this still required in C++17, Which allows inline variables to be initialized in the class?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk In C++17 (I cite the standard) _a function or static data member declared with the constexpr specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable_. Therefore things changed with C++17 actually.