# Linker error with static constant that doesn't seem to be odr-used

Tags: c++, c++14, one-definition-rule

The definition in the standard for odr-used is pretty confusing when you get into the details (at least, for me it is). I generally rely on the informal definition of "If a reference is taken", *except* when an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is available. For integral constants, they should be treated as rvalues, which seems like it should be excluded from the reference rule. Here is my sample code that is failing to link:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    static constexpr int MIN_VALUE { 5 };
    int m_otherValue = 10;
};

Test::Test()
{
    m_otherValue = std::max(m_otherValue, MIN_VALUE);
}

int main()
{
    Test t;
}
```

And the linker error that I get:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
/tmp/main-e2122e.o: In function `Test::Test()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `Test::MIN_VALUE'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Live sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d4c27d6b7683fe8

Why is the definition of `MIN_VALUE` required? It's just a constant to a literal value, the compiler should optimize this out as `std::max(m_otherValue, 5)`. So I just don't get it.

Comment: gcc compiles it http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84d384ce0af8bbd7

Comment: I should also add this failed the same way as my sample using GCC 4.9 in the Android NDK r10 release, with c++14 enabled. I'm not sure why g++ is working fine on Coliru

Comment: @RSahu That link tells me nothing more than I already know, which is that the compiler is not required to provide a diagnostic for ODR violation. That doesn't help me figure out why ODR is obviously being violated here.

Comment: So take this [odd example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28506342/1708801) where I quote the relevant section ... it not only has to yield a constant expression but also the lvalue to rvalue conversion has to be applied or it has to be a discarded value exprssion which does not apply since the arguments as passed by reference. I don't have time to post a detailed answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) takes its arguments by reference, not by value. Performing the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and then constructing a temporary object from that rvalue is not allowed. `std::max` *could* be checking that the two arguments are references to the same object, for all the compiler knows, and that check would be required to evaluate as `true` if called as `std::max(MIN_VALUE, MIN_VALUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read a reference for [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) you will see that it takes it arguments by *reference*, and according to [this odr-used reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use)

> Informally, an object is odr-used if ... a reference is bound to it ...

Since you pass `MIN_VALUE` to a function which takes a reference, the member is *odr-used* and needs a separate definition.

Comment: I understand *that* much, I'm just seeing if the lvalue-to-rvalue piece of the description (which you have not shown) changes the behavior. Basically, hvd's answer nailed that specific concern on the head.